# How do I get all users in my company with a specific filter in microsoft graph API

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

With Microsoft Graph API, I'm trying to get all users in my company but with a specific filter such as mail = (*@company.com) .. The reason I cannot just use /users is because we have many third-party and administrator (dup) accounts. I just want to retrieve the ones with a valid *@company.com email.

I've tried a few of these, but does not work:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=mail eq '*@company.com'
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(mail, '*@company.com')
```

I should also mention I am using POSTMAN to test and will implement into the Microsoft Graph SDK for PHP (msgraph-sdk-php).

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to achieve ending of the particular string but Microsoft Graph endpoints currently don't support `endsWith` or similar query parameters. From the [documentation on query parameters](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#filter).

Suggestion is to use PowerShell instead.

**Example,**

```
$Users=Get-AzureADUser -All:$true | Where-Object {$_.UserPrincipalName -clike "*onmicrosoft.com"} | Select UserPrincipalName
```

Comment: Would you happen to know how to do this with the MSGRAPH PHP SDK ?

Comment: Please raise it as a new question with sample code/trying to achieve info. I  try to help by going through it.